# zendframework2 upload file

Tags: file-upload, zend-framework2

I have a form with multiple fields of type file. foto1, foto2, foto3, foto4, foto5, foto6 
only the first field is required. Use the code that you see below to upload file.

this method is invoked inside a normal controller action after check form validity

```
private function uploadFile($file,$methodName,$idCategoriaEvento,&$categoriaEventoEntity){
    $obj = new \stdClass();
    try{
        //unset($_FILES['fotoGrande'],$_FILES['fotoBanner'],$_FILES['foto1'],$_FILES['foto2'],$_FILES['foto3'],$_FILES['foto4'],$_FILES['foto5'],$_FILES['foto6']);
        if(!empty($file['tmp_name'])){
            $getBasePath = new Getbasepath($this);
            $this->getCurConfig();
            $path_origine = $file['name'];
            $ext = pathinfo($path_origine, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $file_name = $file['tmp_name'];

            $new_file = $getBasePath->getPath().$this->config['ristotram']['categoria_foto_path']. $idCategoriaEvento . "/" . $path_origine;

            $upload_obj = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();

            $upload_obj->addFilter('File\Rename',array(
                'source' => $path_origine,
                'target' => $new_file,
                'overwrite' => true
            ));


            if($upload_obj->receive()) {
                //$categoriaEventoEntity->$methodName($path_origine);
                $obj->s = true;
                $obj->i = "";
            }else{
                $obj->s = false;
                $obj->i = implode("<br />",$upload_obj->getErrors());
            }
        }else{
            $obj->s = true;
            $obj->i = "";
        }
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        $obj->s = false;
        $obj->i = $upload_obj->getErrors();
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

The method signature contains the following values

```
$file, -----> $_FILES['foto1']
$methodName,--------> un metodo della mia entità che invoco per valorizzare la sessione
$idCategoriaEvento->un indice che mi serve per specificare il path,
&$categoriaEventoEntity --------> la mia entità
```

the file is not move to destination but no errors is showed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok code was wrong

```
private function uploadFile($file,$methodName,$idCategoriaEvento,&$categoriaEventoEntity){
    $obj = new \stdClass();
    try{
        if(!empty($file['tmp_name'])){
            $this->getCurConfig();
            $file_name = $file['name'];
            $file_temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
            $new_file = $this->plgBasePath->getPath().$this->config['ristotram']['categoria_foto_path']. $idCategoriaEvento . "/" . $file_name;
            $upload_obj = new Http();
            $upload_obj->addFilter('File\Rename',array(
                'source' => $file_temp_name,
                'target' => $new_file,
                'overwrite' => true
            ));
            if($upload_obj->receive()) {
                $categoriaEventoEntity->$methodName($file_name);
                $obj->s = true;
                $obj->i = "";
            }else{
                $obj->s = false;
                $obj->i = implode("<br />",$upload_obj->getErrors());
            }
        }else{
            $obj->s = true;
            $obj->i = "";
        }
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        $obj->s = false;
        $obj->i = $upload_obj->getErrors();
    }
    return $obj;
}
```